# windows xp home edition - blocking users from changing display settings

Tags: windows-xp, display

I am computer admin for a call center and i want to block all user accounts from changing the Display settings.

nothing i found online helped with xp home edition.

Answer (score 2):

Your best solution would be to upgrade the machines to Windows XP Pro so that you can add them to a Windows domain and control all the machines from within the AD Group Policies.

Comment: Indeed. I'm fairly sure that using XP Home in a call center would be against the licensing policy as well, given that it's *meant* to only allow a restricted number of XP Home machine's on a network

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about XP Home, but did you take a look at this article:

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080114045623AA3R8Jm

> In Windows XP the file desk.cpl is
>   responsible to change display
>   properties. To restrict other users to
>   use the display properties, do the
>   following in sequence:-
>
> 1.Log on as an administrator.
>
> 2.From My computers, go to Tools -> Folder Option, and then choose View
>   tab. The last option is "Use simple
>   file sharing (recommended) ". Uncheck
>   it, and press "OK".
>
> 3. Find the file "desk.cpl" using windows search. The default path is
>      C:\Windows\System32.
> 4. Right click the file, choose Properties, and then you get a
>      "Sharing & Security" tab.
>
> 5.On this tab the top side shows the name of the user and bottom side shows
>   the permission. Click the user from
>   top side, and then change the
>   permissions of full control as "Deny"
>   for that user and press "Ok".
>
> - Now that user is restricted for any change in desk.cpl.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than aim to control user settings through registry settings you might want something like Faronics Deep Freeze:

http://www.faronics.com/html/deepfreeze.asp

This resets the computer to a pre-set image every reboot, so any user changes get wiped. You can keep user files by redirecting My Documents to a separate disk partition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to double-check on an XP machine elsewhere, but [Windows StedyState](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/sharedaccess/default.mspx) might be able to do that for you.